# Custom Expandable ListView is triggering scroll on ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a custom `ExpandableScrollView` (nothing to do with the stock one):

```
public class ExpandableListView extends ListView
{
    public ExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        expand();
    }

    public void expand() {
        ListAdapter mAdapter = getAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, this);

            mView.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        setLayoutParams(params);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

I have an instance of this view inside a `ScrollView`. The problem is that when the layout is inflated and attached to the window, the `ScrollView` scrolls to the bottom.

I'm trying to figure out if it is a problem with the `ScrollView` or with the `ExpandableScrollView`. Maybe should I expand the list on another cycle?

Thanks